# Convert given time to seconds in jooq framework

Tags: mysql, postgresql, jooq, jooq-sbt-plugin

Suppose time is given in HH:MM:SS format.how can we convert this time to second in jooq.

example- Input Time - 2:10:30
outlet- 2*60*60 + 10*60 + 30 =7830 secs

Comment: What are you *actually* using? MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Comment: both MySQL and PostgreSQL. based on the selection, jooq query should be converted to MySQL and PostgreSQL query.

Answer (score 0):

This works in both MySQL and PostgreSQL, assuming you're using the `TIME` data type (otherwise, use [`DSL.time()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#time(org.jooq.Field)) to convert your data to SQL `TIME`):

```sql
with t(v) as (select time '02:10:30')
select extract(hour from v) * 3600
     + extract(minute from v) * 60
     + extract(second from v)
from t
```

jOOQ version:

```java
hour(v).times(inline(3600))
  .plus(minute(v).times(inline(60)))
  .plus(second(v))
```

The following import is implied, as always:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```